# Illegal string offset when printing array values in PHP

Tags: php

Looked at many similiar problems and the solutions didn't help me. I'm getting a strange error message **Warning: Illegal string offset 'officeName' in...** and the var_dump of the variable generating the error looks like this:

```
array(10) {
  ["officeId"]=>
  string(5) "11237"
  ["officeName"]=>
  string(37) "Pro Office Inc."
}
```

The code that produces the errors is:

```
foreach($objects as $key => $value){
    var_dump($value);
}
```

So `$value` is an array. What's wrong with what I'm doing and how can I fix it?

Comment: give the below code also.

Comment: Is `$objects` the array you've put in your post? *Is* `$value` an array?

Comment: what is your complete code like `$objects` and also the PHP version

Comment: PHP version is 5.5.3 and it's not the $objects it's complaining about. It's when I try to use $value['officeName']. So yes. $value IS an array, as seen in the var_dump.

Comment: Check carefully **all** the dumps of `$value`. It is possible that the first item is an array, but one (or many) of the others is not.

Comment: @NorthBridge Thanks. You were right. The last value was not an array, it was a string "length" that showed the length of the array. If you create an answer regarding this, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: @Weblurk I added an answer. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a double check of **every** value from the array, since one of these items may be an array, but there may be others which are not. In such cases it is always better to `var_dump()` the whole `$objects` array instead of each item, since it's easier to spot any error.

Besides, the `Illegal string offset` error usually hints that you're trying to treat a string as an array and/or access it's keys, which don't exist.